# How {condition 1: x(), condition 2: y()}.get(True, None) actually run in python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, if-statement, get

I recently learned about a way to write if-elif-else. For example:

```
a = 10
x = {a < 1: 100, a > 1: 200}.get(True, None)
```

is equal to:

```
a = 10
if a < 1:
    x = 100
elif a > 1:
    x = 200
else:
    x = None
```

They will get the same result `x = 200`

This new way is more elegant so I use it to replace my following if-elif-else code:

```
i = 10
j = 0
class A:
    a = 1
class B:
    a = 2
if i:
    x = A()
elif j:
    x = B()
else:
    x = None
```

to

```
i = 10
j = 0
class A:
    a = 1
class B:
    a = 2
x = {i: A(), j: B()}.get(True, None)
```

However, it didn't run as I wished:

```
>>> x.a
None
```

In my opinion, the output of `x.a` should be `1` because `i > 0`.

How to explain this?

Comment: Besides your question, it's prob. not the best way to learn the language using this type of example.  `Readability counts`...

Comment: change it to ```x = {bool(i): A(), bool(j): B()}.get(True, None)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Not a direct answer to your question)*

> I recently learned about a way to write if-elif-else.

Rather than:

```
a = 10
x = {a < 1: 100, a > 1: 200}.get(True, None)
```

Prefer this:

```
a = 10
x = 100 if a < 1 else 200 if a > 1 else None
```

Which is really more comprehensive, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

In python `True` is equal to `1`. They are basically same thing. When you say `dict.get(True)` you are actually saying `dict.get(1)`. If there is something that is equal to `1`, its value will be returned otherwise `None` will be returned.

In your question:

```
i = 10
j = 0
x = {i: A(), j: B()}.get(True, None)
```

the dict `x` does not have a key which is equal to `1` so you get `None`.

Also *less code* does not always mean it is better. You should prefer writing this code with `if` statements because *readability counts...*